# How to parse the string in javascript (NodeJs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, html-parsing

I want to parse the string:

```
https:&#x2F;&#x2F;google.com, https:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.youtube.com&#x2F;
```

into the normal text like:

```
https://google.com, https://www.youtube.com/
```

In there any npm package available out there to do this job? Please help.
Thanks :)

Comment: Where is the string coming from?

Comment: Those are "HTML entities". Try the [he](https://www.npmjs.com/package/he) package, or the [html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities) package to decode them.